# Datepicker BeforeShowDay usando web api

Tags: jquery, ajax

Boa noite, estou precisando fazer um calendário(usando datepicker do jquery ui), onde as datas que constam no banco de dados, precisam aparecer destacadas.
Porém eu não faço ideia de como fazer.
Estou consumindo uma webapi (local), que pega as informações do Sql Server, o backend da web api está ok, e se tento utilizar fora do datepicker, as datas com os eventos aparecem tbm!
Dependendo do evento, as datas precisam ou não de um botão para ficha de inscrição
(Creio que eu tenha que usar um if else), porém sou novo em javascript e não sei como fazer... alguém poderia me ajudar?
Segue abaixo o que eu consegui fazer até agora:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm',
        dayNamesMin: ['D', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'Q', 'S', 'S', 'D'],
        monthNamesShort:["Jan","Fev","Mar","Abr","Mai","Jun","Jul","Ago","Set","Out","Nov","Dez"],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,

        beforeShowDay: //aqui viria a função para destacar as datas dos eventos
            if (/*aqui viria a condição se o evento precisa de ficha de inscrição*/) {

            } else {
                //aqui viria se o evento não precisa de ficha de inscrição
            }
        },
        onSelect: //aqui abre um dialog ou um alert para aparecer o evento para o usuário
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });

            }

        }
    });`
```